# Share remotes with development team

Tags: git

Is there anyway to share the remotes I have setup in a git repo when the repo is cloned by others. I can think of two instances where this would be helpful.

1. If you use git subtrees, anyone wanting to update the subtree folder will need to know what remote you were using.
2. If you fork a project. It seems like it would be helpful for anyone joining your project to see that you did indeed start your project as a fork and they can see where it was forked from.

The only way I can think of to accomplish this is to state so via side channels (project wiki/website/README) or include some kind of post clone setup script that a user can run after cloning.

I'm betting that there is a reason git does not support what I am asking, if it does not. Can someone help me understand the reason if there is no way to accomplish this?

Comment: You are asking too much from `the stupid content tracker™`. The closest thing is submodules I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to distributed nature of git. You are trying to force others which remotes to use. However, each dev may want different remotes, e.g. to have their own mirror, to pass through a firewall, etc. If it is for a well defined team sitting in the same office, then a wiki/website is a good approach.

Placing this kind of information/configuration inside a repo itself is not very branch-friendly. If configuration changes, it means you need to merge the change into all branches, which is cumbersome. Luckily, git allows to have several history DAGs in the same repository. The trick is to create an orphan branch for configuration:

```
git checkout --orphan config
# you have empty working copy
vi init.sh # write init script
git add init.sh
git commit -m "Write init.sh"
git checkout master # back to work
```

Then you could use `git show` command to extract the script even if it is not checked out in your wc, e.g.:

```
git show config:init.sh | sh # runs the init.sh shell script
```

Comment: I didn't know about the orphan branch concept... thats pretty cool!